# Creating a static array without changing thousands of lines of code

Tags: php, arrays, static

We have a class that holds a public array called `$saved` that contains lots of data required to share between methods (example below)...

```
class Common {
    public $saved = array();

    public function setUser($data) {
        $this->saved['user_data'] = $data;
    }

    public function getUserID() {
        return $this->saved['user_data']['id'];
    }
}
```

There are literally thousands of lines of code that work like this.

The problem is that new instance of classes that extend `Common` are being made within some methods so when they access `$saved` it does not hold the same data.

The solution is to make `$saved` a static variable, however I can't change all of the references to `$this->saved` so I want to try and keep the code identical but make it act static.

Here is my attempt to make `$this->saved` calls static...

```
class PropertyTest {
    private $data = array();

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
            return $this->data[$name];
        }

        return null;
    }

    public function __isset($name) {
        return isset($this->data[$name]);
    }

    public function __unset($name) {
        unset($this->data[$name]);
    }
}

class Common {
    public $saved;
    private static $_instance;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->saved = self::getInstance();
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (self::$_instance === null) {
            self::$_instance = new PropertyTest();
            self::$_instance->foo = array();
        }
        return self::$_instance->foo;
    }
}
```

This doesn't quite work when setting a variable it doesn't seem to stay static (test case below)...

```
class Template extends Common {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->saved['user_data'] = array('name' => 'bob');
        $user = new User();
    }
}

class User extends Common {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->saved['user_data']['name'] .= " rocks!";
        $this->saved['user_data']['id'] = array(400, 10, 20);
    }
}

$tpl = new Template();
print_r($tpl->saved['user_data']);
```

`$this->saved` is empty when `User` gets initialized and doesn't seem to be the same variable, the final `print_r` only shows an array of name => bob.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to me you need a global variable. You could dress it up as a singleton but in the end it's just a global variable.

Comment: @jeroen, I always laughed when people said how evil global was and how it should be replaced with a singleton. They are both the same evil XD.

Comment: @Xeoncross Very true, although I have yet to see a program / script without global variables...

Comment: @fire It seems to me your main problem is stuff like `$this->data[$name] = $value;` in classes that extend from `Common`. If you use getters and setters from `Common` consequently, you will have lots of freedom to change it to however you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved the problem, by making `$this->saved` a reference to a static variable it works...

```
class Common {
    private static $savedData = array();
    public $saved;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->saved =& self::$savedData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I have to say that, IMO, it is not **that good** to use an instance's property as a class's property (`$saved` is not declared as `static` but its value is shared with all instance).

Here is a working version http://codepad.org/8hj1MOCT, and here is the commented code. Basically, the trick is located in using both [ArrayAccess interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) and the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

```
class Accumulator implements ArrayAccess {

    private $container = array();
    private static $instance = null;

    private function __construct() {
    }

    public function getInstance() {
        if( self::$instance === null ) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->container[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->container[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]) ? $this->container[$offset] : null;
    }

}


class Common {
    public $saved = null;


    public function __construct() {
        // initialize the "saved" object's property with the singleton
        // that variable can be used with the array syntax thanks to the ArrayAccess interface
        // so you won't have to modify your actual code
        // but also, since it's an object, this local "$this->saved" is a reference to the singleton object
        // so any change made to "$this->saved" is in reality made into the Accumulator::$instance variable
        $this->saved = Accumulator::getInstance();
    }

    public function setUser($data) {
        $this->saved['user_data'] = $data;
    }

    public function getUser() {
        return $this->saved['user_data'];
    }

}


class Template extends Common {

    // you can redeclare the variable or not. Since the property is inherited, IMO you should not redeclare it, but it works in both cases
    // public $saved = null;

    public function __construct() {
        // maybe we can move this initialization in a method in the parent class and call that method here
        $this->saved = Accumulator::getInstance();
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks but it suffers the same problem that I have provided in my last code sample, see it in action here http://codepad.org/VC3HX0lW you should see name => bob rocks! and an array of id

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a number of issues with this implementation that could well come back to bite you. However, in your current implementation your contructing a new instance (albeit through a static call) every time.

Instead use getInstance() as your singleton hook, and make your __construct private, as you'll only be accessing it from with the context of the Common class.

Like so:

```
class Common {
    public $saved;

    private static $_instance;

    private function __construct() {
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (self::$_instance === null) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
            ... any other modifications you want to make ....
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
}
```

And don't ever run parent::_construct(), instead always use the getInstance() method.

You might also want to ditch the idea of extending this singleton class. This is really a bad antipattern and could cost you a number of issues in the long run. Instead just maintain a `Common` class that other classes can read / write to. As its a singleton you don't need to worry about injection.